# What does the below snippet mean?

Tags: javascript, lwc

I’m trying to understand the syntax but it all feels new to me. I see an anonymous function in an anonymous function followed by a comma and a class. Please help me understand the syntax..

```
e => (function(e) {
if ("function" != typeof e.prototype.dispatchEvent) throw new TypeError(`${e} must be an Element type`)
}(e), class extends e {
[i](e, t) {
    n.getService(this).navigateTo(e, {
        replace: t
    })
} [a](e) {
    return n.getService(this).generateUrl(e)
}
})
```

Comment: there is something missing on the first line. Did you forget an equal sign? also: it references two undefined variables `a` and `i`....

Comment: @trincot NavigationMixin is imported in lightning web component. I have console logged it and pasted here. All I’m trying to understand is the anonymous function

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation

Comment: Look up documentation for "comma operator", "template literal", "class expression", "computed property names", "immediately executed function expression", ...

Comment: Parentheses after a function indicates that it is a `self-invoking function`. In this case, not only is the function automatically invoked, but `e` is passed as a parameter into it.

Comment: @kojow7 why is there a class followed by ‘,’ does that mean anything in JavaScript?

Comment: @user61140 Did you do a search on "comma operator" as trincot suggested?

Comment: @kojow7 the above snippet does return a class and there’s no such documentation, but from the below answer this fits https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is invalid syntax: `NavigationMixin` should be followed by an equal sign to be valid.

Secondly, this code references undefined variables `a` and `i`.

Let's break it down:

`NavigationMixin` is a function that takes one argument: `e`, which should be a class/constructor that is or inherits from `Element`. The function is an arrow function which uses the arrow expression syntax, meaning there is no block, nor a return statement. The expression that follows `=>` evaluates to the returned value.

The expression consists of the comma operator. The left operand of this operator is:

```
(function(e) {
  if ("function" != typeof e.prototype.dispatchEvent) throw new TypeError(`${e} must be an Element type`)
}(e)
```

This is a so-called "immediately invoked function expression" (IIFE). The anonymous function is executed with `e` as argument, and it clearly serves to perform a validation on `e`. The function does not return anything, nor would that be useful. It's only purpose is to trigger an error if the validation does not pass.

Then we move to the second operand of the comma operator:

```
class extends e {
  [i](e, t) {
    n.getService(this).navigateTo(e, {
        replace: t
    })
  } 
  [a](e) {
    return n.getService(this).generateUrl(e)
  }
})
```

This is a class expression. It defines two members on the prototype. Those members have computed names, which is why they have the `[]` syntax: The value of `i` determines the name of the first member and its value is a function:

```
(e, t) {
  n.getService(this).navigateTo(e, {
      replace: t
  })
}
```

The second member on the prototype also has a dynamic name, determined by the value of `a`, and it is also a function.

Finally, the comma operator evaluates the two operands, and ignores the value of the first, and returns the value of the second. So the overall function -- when executed -- returns a class that extends the given class with two methods, whose names are dynamically determined by two variables `a` and `i`.

The code does not give a clue about those two variables.

Comment: Thank You!! For the detailed description.